# How can I use Async Storage to save my data? - React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new to using Async, let alone async storage. I have literally no idea what I'm doing my goal is to basically make use setWorkouts() to set workouts to the values I get from asyncstorage, and use this to save the workouts that are set.

Short Question: How can I save my data using Async Storage?

Code:

```
const submitHandler = async (text, reps, sets) => {
    if(text.length > 0 && reps.length > 0 && sets.length > 0){
      if(text.length <= 40){
        let newWorkout = {
          name: text,
          key: Math.random().toString(),
          reps: reps,
          sets: sets
        };
        writeData = async () => {
          try {
            await AsyncStorage.multiSet(['workouts', [
              newWorkout,
              ...workouts
            ]])
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        }
        await Promise.all(AsyncStorage.getItem('workouts')).then((data) => {
          console.log(data[0])
        })
      }else {Alert.alert('Whoops!', "You entered over 40 characters! Shorten it up a bit!", [{text: 'Close '}])}
    }else {Alert.alert('Whoops!', "Make sure to enter something in each field!", [{text: 'Close '}])}
  }
```

Any help is useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data in async storage with any method we have to parse data in a string instead of passing objects in async storage functions we can convert objects to a string using JSON.stringify.

so, we can try the below code example:

```
const writeData = async (newWorkout) => {
   try {
       await AsyncStorage.multiSet(['workouts', JSON.stringify([
           newWorkout,
           ...workouts
       ]]))
   } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
   }
}

const submitHandler = async (text, reps, sets) => {
    if(text.length > 0 && reps.length > 0 && sets.length > 0){
      if(text.length <= 40){
        let newWorkout = {
          name: text,
          key: Math.random().toString(),
          reps: reps,
          sets: sets
        };
        await writeData(newWorkout)
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('workouts').then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
      } else {
          Alert.alert('Whoops!', "You entered over 40 characters! Shorten it up a bit!", [{text: 'Close '}])
      }
   } else {
       Alert.alert('Whoops!', "Make sure to enter something in each field!", [{text: 'Close '}])}
    } 
}
```

For more details related to set values using async storage and get values from async storage, check-out the official async storage docs.

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api/

Comment: Hey, sorry to inform but the code doesn't seem to be working! It keeps logging undefined, am I somehow using it wrong? Sorry for the inconvenience. Here's the code.


await Promise.all(AsyncStorage.getItem('workouts')).then((data) => {
        console.log(data[0])
})

Comment: There is a mismatch in the answer as I observed, please check it out...  have a try to replacing data[0] with data

Comment: @Hex also keep the writeData method outside the submitHandler to store data first and then retrieve it from async storage.